# Getting Floor Division and Remainder at same time in 2 separate variables

Tags: python, optimization

Is there a python built-in (or just optimized) function to get the floor division and remainder at the same time in two separate variables?

**Example:**

```
a, b = 10 divided by 4
```

**Desired results:**

```
a = 2
b = 2
```

*I need this to be an optimized solution.*

**Performance results:**

First piece of code:

```
for i in range(10000000):
    a, b = divmod(i, 5)
took 3.99 seconds to run
```

Second piece of code:

```
for i in range(10000000):
    a = i // 5
    b = i % 5
took 2.56 seconds to run
```

**Remarks:**

Read @casevh answer for a more detailed explanation.

tldr: divmod() works better if numbers are big.

Comment: I am guessing you are not after this code but thought would check: 
a=10
b=2
div=a//b
mod=a%b

Comment: @KatiaPunter I was looking for some kind of built in function because sometimes those are much faster. But I'll time that solution as well and see which performs better. Thanks

Comment: @joaoavf Where did you get these numbers? `took 2.56 seconds to run` and `took 3.99 seconds to run`

Comment: @KatiaPunter, your solution is actually faster

Comment: @Elis just ran that in my PC, if you can replicate that I would appreciate

Comment: @joaoavf You did not answer to my question!

Comment: @Elis yes I did, you should make a better question if you want a different answer.

Comment: @joaoavf You are avoiding answering to my question! You did understand my question very well. I am out! Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks @joaoavf.

Comment: @Elis I didn't understand what you want. But I will try to read some minds. I used `time.time()` method to calculate `start_time` and `finish_time` and then did `finish_time - start_time` to get how long it took for each function. Is that what you wanted me to answer?

Comment: @joaoavf which you think is faster based on the results you got?

Comment: @ElisByberi, to simplify the post.

Comment: @joaoavf Well, it made post more difficult!

Comment: @VanPeer I don't get this question, but `a = i // 5` and `b = i % 5` is faster

Comment: @Elis why should I use `timeit` module rather than `time` module?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this. this will help you.

```
a,b = divmod(10,2)
```

it will return both value

Comment: Am I missing something? Because that just gives you `a=2` and `b=2`, not what OP asked for where `b=0.5`.

Comment: Oh, he edited the question to ask for just plain `a % b`. Fair enough.

Comment: This attends exactly what I need. I will test it for performance. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KarlReid, yes this works great as well. My question was not that good, sorry.

Comment: What did you write first in your answer? OP edited `a = 2; b = 2` at `2017-11-22 12:33:06Z` and you did answer this at `2017-11-22 12:31:01Z`. Do you use time travel or something?

Answer (score 11):

There is a significant difference in performance if you use larger numbers.

Here is an example using both small and large numbers:

```
$ py27 -m timeit -s "a=123;b=7" "divmod(a,b)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0913 usec per loop
$ py27 -m timeit -s "a=123;b=7" "a//b;a%b"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.047 usec per loop
$ py27 -m timeit -s "a=123333333333333333333333333333333333333;b=7222222222222222222" "divmod(a,b)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.165 usec per loop
$ py27 -m timeit -s "a=123333333333333333333333333333333333333;b=7222222222222222222" "a//b;a%b"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.232 usec per loop
```

Why the difference?

divmod() requires a function call while // and % are operators. There is additional overhead for a function call relative to operators. So when the cost of the computation is minimal, the overhead of calling a function is much greater than the actual cost of the calculation(s).

For larger numbers, divmod() is faster. divmod() calculates both the quotient and remainder at the same time and returns both of them. The // and % operators each calculate the quotient and remainder but only return one of the results.

divmod() has more overhead but only performs one division. // and % have less overhead but perform two divisions. As long as the overhead is large compared to time to perform division, divmod() will be slower. But once the cost of a division is greater than the overhead, divmod() will be faster.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your insight.

Comment: BTW, I wonder why no one thought of a `/%` operator instead of the `divmod` function. We have `//` and `%`, `/%` would sum them up nicely, I think.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for `divmod()` library function

Here is a [link to its docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod)

Example

```
>>> a, b = divmod(10, 4)
>>> print a, b
>>> 2 2
```